# Install D3 on Meteor Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to integrate D3 and topojson using Meteor + Angular2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import template from './d3map.component.html';
import * from 'd3'

@Component({
  selector: 'd3map',
  template
})
export class D3MapComponent {}
```

I have also used below meteor command to install d3

```
meteor npm install --save d3
```

However, I get the below error

```
client/imports/app/d3map/d3map.component.ts (4, 15): Cannot find module 'd3'.
```

Any working examples/plunkr would help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like d3 is not installed.Do one thing go to .meteor folder of your project and open your packages file using any editor. check if D3 is installed or not in the list.

if not installed use  `meteor add d3js:d3`  to install it. or some other package from atmospherejs.com

for reference try one of these. whichever works for you.

```
import * as D3 from 'd3/index';

import * as D3 from 'd3';
```